# How should I use Rails to index and query a join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, devise

I have a ruby on Rails 4 app, using devise and with a User model and a Deal model.

I am creating a `user_deals` table for has_many/has_many relationship between User and Deal.

Here is the migration

```
class CreateUserDeals < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
    create_table :user_deals do |t|
        t.belongs_to :user
      t.belongs_to :deal
      t.integer         :nb_views

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

When a user load a Deal (for example Deal id= 4), I use a method called `show`

```
controllers/deal.rb
#for the view of the Deal page
def show
end
```

In the view of this Deal id=4 page, I need to display the nb of views of the Devise's `current_user` **inside the Deal page the user is currently on**.

```
deal/show.html

here is the nb of views of user: <% current_user.#{deal_id}.nb_views%>
```

Lets' say I have  10M+ `user_deals` lines, I wanted to know if I should use an index

```
add_index :user_deals, :user_id
add_index :user_deals, :deal_id
```

or maybe

```
add_index(:deals, [:user_id, deal_id])
```

Indeed in other situations I would have said Yes, but here I don't know how Rails works behind the scenes. It feels as if Rails is aware of what to do without me needing to speed up the process,...as if when Rails loads this view that there is no SQL query (such as 'find the nb of views WHERe `user_id= x` and `deal_id= Y`')....because I'm using just for the `current_user` who is logged-in (via devise's `current_user`) and for `deal_id` Rails knows it as we are on the very page of this deal (show page) so I just pass it as a parameter.

So do I need an index to speed it up or not?

Comment: Rails hasn't to do anything with the indexing itself. The database manages the indexes and rails only delegates to create them. So it depends on your database. I would recommend you to create indexes for foreign keys because they are often joined to other tables. In my opinion you should always create indexes for foreign keys. And for Multicolumn Indexes I would use an index only if i have a `many to many` association or if I have to check for uniqueness in a specific scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question on indexes is a good one. Rails **does** generate SQL* to do its magic so the normal rules for optimising databases apply.

The magic of devise only extends to the current_user. It fetches their details with a SQL query which is efficient because the user table created by devise has helpful indexes on it by default. But these aren't the indexes you'll need.

Firstly, there's a neater more idiomatic way to do what you're after

```
class CreateUserDeals < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :users, :deals do |t|
      t.integer :nb_views
      t.index [:user_id, :deal_id]
      t.index [:deal_id, :user_id]
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

You'll notice that migration included two indexes. If you never expect to create a view of all users for a given deal then you won't need the second of those indexes. However, as @chiptuned says indexing each foreign key is nearly always the right call. An index on an integer costs few write resources but pays out big savings on read. It's a very low cost default defensive position to take.

You'll have a better time and things will feel clearer if you put your data fetching logic in the controller. Also, you're showing a *deal* so it will feel right to make that rather than `current_user` the centre of your data fetch.

You can actually do this query without using the `through` association because you can do it without touching the users table. (You'll likely want that `through` association for other circumstances though.) 
Just `has_many :user_deals` will do the job for this.

To best take advantage of the database engine and do this in one query your controller can look like this:

```
def show
  @deal = Deal.includes(:user_deals)
              .joins(:user_deals)
              .where("user_deals.user_id = ?", current_user.id)
              .find(params["deal_id"])
end
```

Then in your view...

```
I can get info about the deal: <%= @deal.description %>
```

And thanks to the `includes` I can get user nb_views without a separate SQL query: 
    <%= @deal.user_deals.nb_views %>

* If you want to see what SQL rails is magically generating just put `.to_sql` on the end. e.g. `sql_string = current_user.deals.to_sql` or `@deal.to_sql`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use an index to speed up the querying of the `user_deals` records.  Definitely at least on `user_id`, but probably both `[:user_id, :deal_id]` as you stated.

As for why you don't see a SQL query...

First off, your code in the view appears to be incorrect.  Assuming you have set up a `has_many :deals, through: :user_deals` association on your `User` class, it should be something like:

`here is the nb of views of user: <%= current_user.deals.find(deal_id).nb_views %>`

If you see the right number showing up for `nb_views`, then a query should be made when the view is rendered unless `current_user.deals` is already being loaded earlier in the processing or you've got some kind of caching going on.

If Rails is "aware", there is some kind of reason behind it which you should figure out.  Expected base Rails behavior is to have a SQL query issued there.

Answer (score 1):

Is a cleaner way of indexing other tables not:

```
class CreateUserDeals < ActiveRecord::Migration

   def change
      create_table :user_deals do |t|
         t.references :user
         t.references :deal
         t.integer :nb_views

         t.timestamps
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: I believe `belongs_to` and `references` are synonyms

Comment: @Adamantish `references` also adds an index for the column in Rails 4, so thats how it differs.  If the author goes with a multicolumn index, then they'll want to use something closer to their migration than this one suggested.